# Why is two-way binding in silverlight not working?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, two-way-binding

According to how Silverlight TwoWay binding works, when I change the data in the FirstName field, it should change the value in CheckFirstName field.

Why is this not the case?

### ANSWER:

Thank you Jeff, that was it, for others: here is [the full solution with downloadable code](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=61).

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="GridCustomerDetails">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">First Name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Last Name:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>

        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Address:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Address}"/>

    </Grid>

    <Border Background="Tan" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CheckFirstName"/>
    </Border>

</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.FirstName = "Jim";
    customer.LastName = "Taylor";
    customer.Address = "72384 South Northern Blvd.";

    GridCustomerDetails.DataContext = customer;

    Customer customerOutput = (Customer)GridCustomerDetails.DataContext;
    CheckFirstName.Text = customer.FirstName;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Customer` type has to support [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(VS.95).aspx) in order for the binding to know when your `FirstName` property value has changed.

This [tutorial](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/silverlight-data-binding) may help you in getting your code to work.

Comment: You could also derive from `DependencyObject` and make `FirstName` a dependency property.  Jeff's solution is more appropriate, but you have the two choices.

Comment: @carlmon: Good point, that is an alternative approach to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

solution is use element binding for `CheckFirstName`

Answer (score 1):

Your controls inside of the Grid container have no idea what FirstName, LastName, and Address are. I think that you need to bind your grid to the object in the codebehind:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridCustomerDetails" DataContext="Customer">
```

Now every control inside of that container can be bound to a property of Customer. You bind it like so:

```
<TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
         Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In your code behind, make sure that "Customer" is  a class object, and is declared publicly.

If this doesn't work, try adding an x:Name="" to the page declarations and namespaces at the top.

I hope this helps!