# Silverlight 5 clearing Data Object on Binding with XamGrid using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, infragistics, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to bind a data object to XamGrid.  However, the grid comes up blank.  This worked in Silverlight 4, but no longer works in Silverlight 5.  Examining code reveals that after initialization the data object that is bound to the grid is blank though it enters with data.

Here is the .xaml that is relevant

```
<custCtrls:TcGroupBox Header="Users" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl>
            <ig:XamGrid x:Name="igUsersGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="Auto" Height="159" ItemsSource="{Binding Users.Rows, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedRowsCollectionChanged="igUsersGrid_SelectedRowsCollectionChanged" Loaded="igUsersGrid_Loaded">
                <ig:XamGrid.RowSelectorSettings>
                    <ig:RowSelectorSettings EnableRowNumbering="False" Visibility="Visible" />
                </ig:XamGrid.RowSelectorSettings>
                <ig:XamGrid.SelectionSettings>
                    <ig:SelectionSettings RowSelection="Single" ColumnSelection="None" CellSelection="None" CellClickAction="SelectRow"/>
                </ig:XamGrid.SelectionSettings>
                <ig:XamGrid.Columns>
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" Width="165" MinimumWidth="{StaticResource DefaultMinimumColWidth}" />
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" Width="165" MinimumWidth="{StaticResource DefaultMinimumColWidth}" />
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" Width="165" MinimumWidth="{StaticResource DefaultMinimumColWidth}" />
                    <ig:TemplateColumn Key="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" Width="115" IsReadOnly="True" MinimumWidth="{StaticResource DefaultMinimumColWidth}" >
                        <ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ig:XamMaskedEditor Value="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}" Mask = "(###)###-####" ValidationMode="LostFocus" IsReadOnly="True" Template="{StaticResource XamMaskedEditorControlTemplate1}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
                    </ig:TemplateColumn>
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="Email" HeaderText="Email" Width="160" MinimumWidth="{StaticResource DefaultMinimumColWidth}" />
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="RoleName"  HeaderText="RoleName" Width="160" MinimumWidth="{StaticResource DefaultMinimumColWidth}" />
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="UserId" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <ig:TextColumn Key="RoleId" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </ig:XamGrid.Columns>
            </ig:XamGrid>                       
        </ContentControl>
    </custCtrls:TcGroupBox>
```

where

```
xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
```

Here is the relevant .cs code that is relevant

```
public bool InitializeView(Object viewData)
    {
        _bInitializingControls = true;
        UserControlData data = viewData as UserControlData;

        _dsoUserMgmt = data.ControlData as dsoUserMgmt;
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = _dsoUserMgmt;

        ShowDefaultForm();
        InitializeMenuBar();

        //Initialize menu and toolbar and show default form
        GetUserRoleNames();

        _dsoUserMgmt.Modified = false;

        if (_SelectedUserId > 0)
            SelectUserGridRow(_SelectedUserId);
        _bInitializingControls = false;
        return true;
    }
```

and here is a snippet of the doUserMgmt.cs object

```
public class dsoUserMgmt : dsoBaseDataSet
{
    protected dtoUsers _Users = new dtoUsers();

    [DataMember]
    public dtoUsers Users
    {
        get { return _Users; }

        set
        {
            Delete(_Users);
            _Users = value;
            Add(_Users);
        }
    }
}
```

When tracing through the code when I hit the following line in the InitializeView()

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = _dsoUserMgmt;
```

then it will call the get to return _Users, but it calls it three times.  The first two contain data, and the third call returns null.  After that point the DataContect, and thusly the grid, are empty.

Any ideas as to what is going on?  This works in another grid that is set up in the same fashion, and this use to work in Silverlight 4.  I found the following links, but they did not help (though they shed some light on possible future issues)

[Binding bug in Silverlight 5?](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/244652.aspx/1)

[Silverlight Data Binding](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/silverlight-data-binding)

Comment: Here is another link that I used as well

[Why is two-way binding in silverlight not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553521/why-is-two-way-binding-in-silverlight-not-working)

Comment: And Microsoft alraedy had some related cases, but not exactly this.

[Silverlight 5 binding issue - binding is not updated](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/720461/silverlight-5-binding-issue-binding-is-not-updated)
 AND 
[StringFormat or Convertor is not triggered when binding is updated in Silverlight 5](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/714760/silverlight-forum-stringformat-or-convertor-is-not-triggered-when-binding-is-updated-in-silverlight-5)

Comment: Is there anything else in your LayoutRoot that is bound to the Users or a property inside Users?  If there is, that would explain why it is hit three times.  Since the grid is bound to Users.Rows, you may want to put a break point on the Rows property getter and see if it is returning a value or not or if it is even being called.